# Convert string version information to integer for easy comparison

Tags: string, lua, integer, version

I am in a process of designing a program that runs end-user scripts written in Lua. The program defines an interface that tells how many parameters are being passed to which function, their order and so on. At some point in the future, the interface may change so I would like to pass a version information of the host program to a script. My common practice is to use MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH format.

The goal is to keep the representation simple as much as possible, so that the information can be processed using arithmetic operations, like so:

```
if program.version < SCRIPT_SUPPORTS_VERSION then
    error ("This version is not supported, please upgrade...")
end
```

Common sense dictates to use integers written in base of sixteen, where each byte represents a part in the version format. Like so:

```
-- Version 1.3.2
-- Compatible with versions >=1.2.0
--
local program = {}
program.version = 0x010302
local SCRIPT_SUPPORTS_VERSION = 0x010200
```

As I mentioned before, this is the first thing that came to my head when thinking about the problem and it seems to work. On other hand, hexadecimal numbers may seem scary to some.

I would like to know your opinion, please propose alternative solutions.

Comment: Why hexadecimals?  Decimals are also good enough: `1020003`

Comment: Why not tables? `{major = 1, minor = 3, patch = 2}`

Comment: Also, there are libraries that deal with this sort of thing, e.g. [semver](https://luarocks.org/modules/kikito/semver) or [version](https://luarocks.org/modules/mashape/version).